# Difference between gerunds and another type of names

Tags: grammar, gerunds

Lets us consider 2 types of names:

type 1 (that I do not know its name): issuance - advice   - completion - confirmation

type 2 (gerund): issuing  - advising - completing - confirming

What is the real difference between those 2 groups? I am very lost because when I translate each word of type 1 to my native language (Arabic), it gives me the same meaning of its corresponding in type 2. And what is type 2 called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first type of noun is the result of the second type of noun.
 The gerund is a verb acting as a noun & its product is the state of being of that first type. 
I produced a sentence. That producing resulted in a production.

Comment: Are there names from type 1 that end with 'ing' ? And how can I distinguish in these cases?

Comment: Can you answer me, please?